# How does this simplify to $\lg{\sqrt{x}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How does $\lg{x}-\lg{\sqrt[3]{x}}-\lg{\sqrt[6]{x}}$ simplify to $\lg{\sqrt{x}}$?

I've tried to get Bagatrix Algebra Solved! to solve it, but it even got the wrong answer... (I checked it by replacing x with 5 and typing it out on a calculator..)

No matter what I do, I end up with an answer that is correct and a bit simplified, but not as simplified as $\lg{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: hint $\log(x^a)=a\log(x)$

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6299/should-the-algebra-tag-be-blacklisted?cb=1

Comment: @AD. So when should I use the $\text{algebra}$ tag?

Comment: Never. For this kind of thing, you should use `algebra-precalculus`.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts No one should in fact use that tag. Please read the tag info http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebra/info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\lg x-\lg\sqrt[3]{x}-\lg\sqrt[6]{x}&=\lg\frac{x}{x^{1/3}\cdot x^{1/6}}\\
&=\lg\frac{x}{x^{\frac13+\frac16}}\\
&=\lg\frac{x}{x^{1/2}}\\
&=\lg\left(x^{1-\frac12}\right)\\
&=\lg x^{1/2}\\
&=\lg\sqrt x\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: How did you go from the second line to the third line?

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts $x^{1/3}\cdot x^{1/6} = x^{1/3 + 1/6} = x^{1/2}$.

Comment: @StudentofHogwarts: I’ve added a couple of extra steps that should answer the question.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for an excellent answer! It seems like I didn't find the answer because I didn't figure out that you could do like you did from the third line to the fourth line..

Answer (score 4):

Do you know these two identities?

$$\sqrt[n]{x}=x^{1/n}$$

$$\lg a^b=b\lg a$$

Comment: Yes -----------------

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\lg\sqrt[n]{x}=\lg\left(x^{1/n}\right)=\frac1n\lg x$$ for any positive integer $n$. That should get you where you need to go, since $\sqrt{x}=\sqrt[2]{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to assume $x > 0$ to have a canonical choice for the branches of $\sqrt[3]x$ and $\sqrt[6]x$. Hint: $\log x^n = n \log x$ generalises to rational $n$.